# Attempted import error: 'app' is not exported from 'firebase/app' (imported as 'firebase') In the React js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I had imported db from firebase

```
import { db } from "./firebase";
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})
```

export const auth = app.auth()
export default app``
but I ended up with an error it's so hard to solve this. Please anyone help me with this. My firebase file looks something like this

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write that code.

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";


const firebaseConfig = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBtEAxMi526TNH9P2x_IzVKWGetoiUdbMg",
  authDomain: "linkedin-clone-f8ade.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "linkedin-clone-f8ade",
  storageBucket: "linkedin-clone-f8ade.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "856416434645",
  appId: "1:856416434645:web:ee438c52afa2866723e55c",
});

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const db = firebase.firestore();
export default firebase;
```